# How to include logging in NUnit

Tags: nunit

What would be an example of a default logger in NUnit  to log the information?

Some documentation says [Log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is not supported now.

Comment: Which documents saying that log4net is not supported, could you give an url?

Comment: Not about Log4net and logging, but related (general debugging in NUnit unit tests): *[How do I get nunit3-console to output my debug to screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405753/how-do-i-get-nunit3-console-to-output-my-debug-to-screen-on-a-windows-box)* - *"in NUnit 3, you should use TestContext.WriteLine(...) in your tests"*. It [works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405753/how-do-i-get-nunit3-console-to-output-my-debug-to-screen-on-a-windows-box#comment110657051_46407376) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal .NET [`Trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) or [`Debug`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) classes to log messages that NUnit will later display.

Comment: Yep but this kind of logs only can be observed whils test run but what if requirement is to save logs from each tests run

Comment: You could do this with custom `TraceListener`s.

Comment: No, it's a .NET [feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx). There's even a [`TextWriterTraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx) that you can use to write to a file.

Comment: but this would be a custom implementation and you can;'t write all NUNit diagnostic messages in this way

Comment: Ah, so it's NUnit messages that you want to write, not your own messages?

Comment: I believe Kumar is asking about NUnit logger

Answer (score 0):

You can add Common.Logging reference (with Log4net) and add ConsoleAppender in your configuration file. After configuring the appender, you will see logging information when running your unit tests.